# iOS UI Test: how to get message of UIAlertController

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

My app has a login screen. If the user presses the login button without entering any text in either the username or password fields, the app will display a `UIAlertController` with an error message.

I am trying to model this logic in UI Tests, and want to assert that the `UIAlertController` is displaying the correct message. However, I can't find a way for the UI Test to access the message property of the alert. Here is the code generated by the test recorder:

```
func testLoginWithoutPasswort() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let emailTextField = app.textFields["email"]
    emailTextField.tap()
    emailTextField.typeText("xxx@gmail.com")
    app.buttons["Login"].tap()
    app.alerts["Error"].collectionViews.buttons["OK"].tap()
}
```

Is there any way I can extract the `String` value of the alert's message, so I can put an assertion on it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't directly test the alert's *message*. You can, however, test if the alert *contains* your error message's copy (at all).

For example, say your alert looks like this:

[image: Alert titled "You won!" with a message "Final Score: 27-25".]

To assert that the alert contains the "Final Score" message, use:

```
XCTAssert(app.alerts.element.staticTexts["Final Score: 27 - 25"].exists)
```

You can also test the **title** of the alert directly:

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.alerts.element.label, "You won!")
```

> More examples available in my [UI Testing Cheat Sheet and Examples](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/) post and [sample app](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is: `alert.elements()[2].name()`
Inside `onAlert` callback function add `alert.logElementTree()` to see AlertView elements. It might be nil, maybe just title is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers above, which I struggled to get to work, there is another way.

Creata a Bool within your UItest method that is false:

```
var alertPressed = false
```

Then add a UIInterruptionMonitor and set the bool to true within it's closure:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System Dialog") {
        (alert) -> Bool in
        alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
        alertPressed = true
        return true
    }
```

Then interact with the app again, and assert that the Bool is true

```
app.tap()
XCTAssert(alertPressed)
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with what the original question asked.